# How to Convert number to uniqueidetifier in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a excel file having Id as some number value( e.g:- Id=125554).
I am trying to store these in database. In database has column has ID as uniqueidentifier DataType.

I am trying Data Conversion from int to DT_GUID but i am getting error:

> Oledb data provider used by oledb adaptor cannot convert between type DT_R8 and DT_GUID

Answer (score 0):

With Id like '125554', you can't convert to type uniqueidentifier (DT_GUID in SSIS).
It require a string with 36 characters to be convert

You should change column type (in database) from uniqueidentifier to int

Comment: is there any other way..?

Comment: why do you want to store a number as uniqueidentifier ?

Comment: My Scenario IS:-  I have a excel file having Id column and has value 15656( some number) . Now from excel file i have store these data in my database. and later i have to update those ID value with GUID value( ex:- 283ad9bc-dc64-427e-bd45-c5cc12d0d140). Can you help me out.?

Comment: sorry but i still don't get what you mean. After insert data of excel file into database as a number, you want to convert it to uniqueidentifier (15656 to 283ad9bc-dc64-427e-bd45-c5cc12d0d140) right? What's the reason for that :)

Comment: No No.. i mean to say that .. after inserted data from excel.. then  i have to update ID Field with GUID database

Comment: After inserting ID field as (23433)(some number) then again i have to use one data flow and connect with some other database (which has ID field as GUID value) and Update those old ID field data(23433) to new ID Field data(i.e GUID value )

Comment: okay, got it. There's no other way, you can't convert int to uniqueidentifier

Comment: if I change int to nvarchar it working.. but it not changing to uniqueidentifer

Comment: because uniqueidentifer comes with special format (36 characters contain some '-')